# Smoothness of determinant of a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, smooth-manifolds

Is the smoothness of the determinant of a metric sufficient to conclude that the metric is smooth? If not, what does the determinant have to do with the smoothness of a metric?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the determinant of the metric? On a Riemannian manifold there is no glbally defined determinant of the metric, as ithat  depends on the chart.

Comment: I'm considering a metric on a chart.

Comment: Then the determinant is obviously smooth, as the entries are smooth functions.

Answer (score 4):

No, the metric can have a smooth determinant in coordinates without being smooth itself. Here’s a simple counterexample: Let $g$ be the metric on $\mathbb R^2$ whose metric is diagonal with diagonal entries $f$ and $1/f$. Then the determinant is $1$ everywhere, but the function $f$ can be as rough as you want.

Comment: What about the opposite, i.e., what if the determinant is non-smooth? Can we directly conclude that the metric is not smooth? I think yes. But, why should one always check whether the determinant is smooth if all the metric components are smooth?

Comment: @Immanuel: The determinant is a polynomial function of the metric coefficients, so if the metric is smooth, its determinant is smooth too by composition. The contrapositive of that statement is the answer to your first question.  I have no idea why anyone would suggest checking smoothness of the determinant separately once you know the metric components are smooth.